# Ext JS - get Ext element in iframe

Tags: iframe, extjs

There is a iframe in DOM, but I want to get a Ext element in it. Is there any ideas?

I have tried two ways:

1. Try to find some Ext functions to get a ext element, but none works now. Btw, I use Ext JS 3.3.
2. Use `document.getElementByTag('iframe')[0].contentDocument` to get the DOM object of IFrame, and then use Ext function to get the element, but don't know how to handle this.

Please give some advises for this one. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to get the whole element or just read one of its properties?

Comment: @third_eye I need get the whole data which is a grid. It's better to get the whole element than just read one of its properties.

Comment: Have you tried with [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)?

Comment: @third_eye based on the second way mentioned in my question, I can get the innerHTML, but I don't know how to get a ext element from this html string. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Can you share some code to give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

inject a JS file into the document after it's loaded on page then manipulate he dom as need!

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of the `select` method with the CSS rule as the first parameter and the `contentDocument` attribute as part of the second parameter. For example:

```
Ext.select("img[class*='x-tree-']", document.getElementById("content").contentDocument.getElementById("pkg_tree_id"))
```

Use the `get` method to wrap the result in an Ext object.

**References**

- [Ext.dom.Query](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query)
- [Ext.get](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-get)